# How do we really link the PyPDF2 to a different version of Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do we really link the PyPDF2 to a different version of Python? I do have several version of Python installed in my Mac (Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.6 etc.,) – itsraghz May 24 at 5:09

Answer (score 0):

best way to do it is creating virtual environments in python as part of project source folders.
conventional folder name for a python virtual environment is .venv

**to create a virtual environment:**

> 1. from command shell cd to project source directory
> 2. run [python] -m venv .venv [python] should be the path of the executable file or python it self if referenced in environment variables.  since there are multiple
>      python versions installed, using python executable path with desired
>      version would be ideal.

this way there can be n number of working environments with different python versions even with different library versions[i.e. for testing purposes]